% processor Time in Activity monitor is greyed out
When I connect to my SQL Server using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) from a remote computer, the "% Processor Time" metric in the Activity Monitor is greyed out and unavailable. However, when I connect to the same server from SSMS installed on the local machine (where the SQL Server instance is running), the "% Processor Time" metric is visible and functioning as expected. Is this the normal behaviour of Activity monitor , If yes please provide proof for this

According to the documentation Open Activity Monitor in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS):

To view actual activity, you must have VIEW SERVER STATE permission. To view the Data File I/O section of Activity Monitor, you must have CREATE DATABASE, ALTER ANY DATABASE, or VIEW ANY DEFINITION permission in addition to VIEW SERVER STATE.
To KILL a process, a user must be a member of the sysadmin or processadmin fixed server roles.

And from What are the minimum permissions for Activity Monitor:

Secondly, add the AD users using the activity monitor to the local OS group Performance Monitor Users. That is needed because Activity monitor is using number of performance counters to visualize data in those graphs.

You may also need to configure your firewall. See the related Q & A Activity Monitor Blocked by Firewall. Set Static Port?
